# looking for GSM SMS component/ActiveX

Tags: c#, c++, c, delphi, activex

I'm looking for a delphi component or ActiveX which can access to GSM devices through serial port.

I need to send and receive binary data sms (8-bit coding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [nrCommLib](http://www.deepsoftware.ru/nrcomm/)
- [TOxygenSMS](http://www.oxygensoftware.com/en//products/tsms/)